# Mimic lightning in Blender's video editing mode

Tags: lighting

I want to do something that I think ought to be rather simple. I’m working in Blender’s video editing mode. What I want to do is simply to light up what is shown in the strip abruptly, mimicking the effect of lightning. I do not want the flashlight itself, just the indirect light of the flashlight in the room the person in the video is in.

hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Blender VSE has a range of color effects you can apply on strips.
The simplest :

1. Select your strip
2. In the properties region > Filter, change the value of Multiply to change the bightness

Then you have modifiers:

- In the Properties region > Modifiers > Add Strip Modifier, try :

  - White Balance
  - Bright/Contrast
  - Curves

Finally you have effect strips:

1. with your strip selected, hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (or click on "Add")
2. in Effect Strip, try :

   - Glow, then change its parameters in the properties region > Effect Strip
   - Color, then  set the blend mode to "Add" (in properties region > Edit Strip) and change the color in Effect Strip.